# Getting safety and extensibility

Tags: haskell

I have a library that includes a type `data Zq q = Zq Int` representing the integers `mod q`. For safety, I'd like to expose some operations on this type (`(+)`, `(*)`, etc), but *not* export the constructor to avoid people circumventing the safety gotten by declaring such a type in the first place.

However, users of the library may reasonably need to declare instances for this type that I as the library author can't predict. To name just a few possible instances: `DeepSeq`, `Storable`, `Unbox`, ...

The only way I know of that allows third parties to make such instances is to export the constructor. (Alternatively, I could define and export a smart constructor and destructor, but this seems to be no better than just exporting the data constructor.)

Is there a way to ensure safety while also allowing third parties to extend the type?

Comment: One option is to export the constructor only from a separate module with `Unsafe` in its name. This way, it's easy for users to do the right thing, but if required, the constructor is still accessible.

Comment: It seems that you want to allow pattern matching on `Zq` but not construction. With `PatternSynonyms` this is easy: `pattern View_Zq a <- Zq a`. You can even go further with GHC >= 7.10 and write an explicit bidirectional pattern synonym, which in an expression context would *check* if the `Int` is the correct size and throw an error otherwise (or just apply `mod q` to the integer if that suits you). In older version you can accomplish the same with a *view* type which is identical to the original, but one cannot convert the view type to the original, and a e.g. `view :: Zq q -> View_Zq q`.

Comment: .. But it seems you have this idea already (3rd paragraph) - why is this no better than exporting the data constructor? You can implement all of the classes you mentioned with the non-abstraction breaking functions `Zq q -> Int` and `IsNat q => Int -> Maybe (Z q)`

Comment: @user2407038 Two points: first, the destructor is rather meaningless because the `Int` doesn't mean anything outside of its context. I'm also concerned about efficiency with that approach: it would be bad if low-level instances (like `Unbox` and `Storable`) were less efficient than strictly required due to using a destructor rather than matching on the type constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most well-formed instances shouldn't require the unsafe raw constructors. `Unbox` etc. are a bit unusually low-level, but other instances should generally be definable in terms of much the same high-level API you'd also use for end applications.

So, I don't really see your concern of *don't know instances ⇒ can't hide constructors*. If you just define the critical close-to-the-metal instances yourself you should be fine.

That said, I often find it rather annoying if a library doesn't export the constructors at all. Even if every instance and everything else *can* be defined only using the high-level API, it *can* make sense to grant unsafe low-level access for a lot of reasons that can't really be forseen. Debugging, special optimisations, simply seeing *what's going on*...
Hence, in a similar vein to Python's [“we're all consenting adults here”](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2003-October/025932.html) philosophy, I'd support kosmikus' suggestion: export the constructors of all important types, but do it in a way that makes it clear that using these directly is unsafe. An extra `Unsafe` module is a good way to achieve this. Simply giving the constructor a technical-sounding name may also be sufficient. And of course document what precisely is unsafe about these exports.